# wxPython: How do I remove spacers from a sizer?

Tags: python, wxpython

I've added a spacer to a sizer like this:

```
self.itemVBox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
self.itemVBox.AddSpacer((0, 5))
```

Is there a way to remove the spacer that I've added or possibly remove/reset all spacers in that sizer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try this:

[How to remove a size(spacer) from a sizer](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wxpython-users/OH3H6IcALXI)

AddSpacer returns a spacer item. As much as I understand, you are looking to remove that spacer, right?

```
spacer = self.itemVBox.AddSpacer((0, 5))
self.itemVBox.remove(spacer)
```

You can also see Sizer API in the wxpython docs:

http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Sizer-class.html